# Laravel 8 routes not working on vps using aapanel as control panel

Tags: routes, vps, laravel-8, controlpanel

I deployed my Laravel 8 website on vps server using aapanel as control panel, the website is running but only the welcome (index page), when I try to add some routes and other pages I get `404 Not Found`.

And the here is the error in log:

```
2020/11/09 11:21:35 [error] 974#0: *839 open() "/www/wwwroot/mywebsite.com/mywebsite/public/hello" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 27.3.121.27, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /hello HTTP/2.0", host: "mywebsite.com"
```

Here are is the location I stored my website on aapanel: `/www/wwwroot/mywebsite.com/mywebsite`

And here is the config for my website running on aapanel:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.htm default.html;
    root /www/wwwroot/mywebsite.com/mywebsite/public;
    
    #SSL-START SSL related configuration, do NOT delete or modify the next line of commented-out 404 rules
    #error_page 404/404.html;
    #HTTP_TO_HTTPS_START
    if ($server_port !~ 443){
        rewrite ^(/.*)$ https://$host$1 permanent;
    }
    #HTTP_TO_HTTPS_END
    ssl_certificate    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    error_page 497  https://$host$request_uri;

    #SSL-END
    
    #ERROR-PAGE-START  Error page configuration, allowed to be commented, deleted or modified
    #error_page 404 /404.html;
    #error_page 502 /502.html;
    #ERROR-PAGE-END
    
    #PHP-INFO-START  PHP reference configuration, allowed to be commented, deleted or modified
    include enable-php-74.conf;
    #PHP-INFO-END
    
    #REWRITE-START URL rewrite rule reference, any modification will invalidate the rewrite rules set by the panel
    include /www/server/panel/vhost/rewrite/mywebsite.com.conf;
    #REWRITE-END
    
    # Forbidden files or directories
    location ~ ^/(\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.git|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md)
    {
        return 404;
    }
    
    # Directory verification related settings for one-click application for SSL certificate
    location ~ \.well-known{
        allow all;
    }
    
    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
    {
        expires      30d;
        error_log off;
        access_log off;
    }
    
    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
    {
        expires      12h;
        error_log off;
        access_log off; 
    }
    access_log  /www/wwwlogs/mywebsite.com.log;
    error_log  /www/wwwlogs/mywebsite.com.error.log;
}
```

And here is code in routes to create new page (not working):

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('hello', function () {
    echo 'It works!';
});
```

Visit the website at: `mywebsite.com` everything works, but when I go to the new page `mywebsite.com/hello` I get `404 Not Found`.

I don't think the code is wrong, maybe this error is caused by other issues like setting the server... Can anyone help me fix this, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In the NGinx config for this site under the line:

```
index index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.htm default.html;
```

add:

```
location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Login to panel > website > Select site name/domain > URL rewrite > select wordpress from dropdown > save

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to PHP settings under disabled functions and  remove (putenv and symlink)